# HP-UFT how to tell if SAP Agentry / WPF image is clickable or disabled

Tags: hp-uft

Is it possible to get an object property for WPF image to find out if it is clickable or disabled.

I have tried these, but clickable and not-clickable images both return true.

```
...WpfImage("WO-Hold").Object.checkAccess
...WpfImage("WO-Hold").GetROProperty("canFocus")
...WpfImage("WO-Hold").object.IsEnabled
```

The WPF application im working from is SAP Agentry, these three buttons are to change the SAP work order status in this image: Play can be clicked. the pause and Green tick cannot be clicked. [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the following:

**Identification property: enabled**

```
...WpfImage("WO-Hold").GetROProperty("enabled")       'returns false If disabled; true if enabled
```

Screenshot:

[image]

OR

**Native Property: Isenabled**

```
......WpfImage("WO-Hold").Object.IsEnabled            'returns false if disabled; true if enabled
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gurman, have tried this but the with the SAP Agentry application being tested, isEnabled = true is returned for clickable and not clickable buttons. Very confusing.